# Set indicator in SQL Select Statment based on WHERE Exist

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have 3 tables:

Table1
Table2
Table3

I want to create a stored procedure that returns an indicator in the Select Statement who's value is set based on a match/no match between Table2 and Table3. The Indicator is not an existing column on any of the 3 tables used in the query.

How can this be accomplished?

For Example:

```
Select
,tb1.Name
,tb2.Address 
,Indicator
From Table1 tb1
 join Table2 tb2
    on tb1.Id = tb2.Id
Where Exist (if tb2.Id = Table3.Id then set Indicator = 'Match' else = 'NoMatch')


Table 1     Id          Name
            1           John
            2           Bob

Table 2     Id          Address        PolicyNumber
            1           105 main st    1234567890 
            2           115 south ave  5555555555 

Table 3     PolicyNumber
            1234567890 
            9999999999
```

Expected Result Set:

```
John,105 main st,Match     
Bob,115 south ave,NoMatch
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Most products have their own, non-ANSI SQL, versions of stored procedures.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement rather in your `SELECT` like

```
case when tb2.Id = Table3.Id then 'Match' else 'NoMatch' end as Indicator
```

Your query would look like

```
Select tb1.Name
,tb2.Address 
,case when tb2.Id = Table3.Id then 'Match' else 'NoMatch' end as Indicator
From Table1 tb1
 join Table2 tb2 on tb1.Id = tb2.Id
 join Table3 on tb2.Id = Table3.Id
```